# Questions about how random effects are specified in lmer

Tags: r, random-effects

I want to write a random effect model for this regression :

```
randeffect<- lmer(effort~bs+bso+fe+st+maj+exp+hw+(randomeslope/randomgroupe))
```

I am beginner in r and actually don't know which code even lmer is useful for random effect model or not, moreover each of the independent variables are generated randomly, so they are not in the one data frame!
My data are :

```
hw<- sample(0:1, 1000, replace =T)
exp<- sample(0:1, 1000, replace = T)
maj<- sample(0:1,1000,replace = T)
st<- sample(0:1,1000,replace = T)
fe<- sample(0:1,1000,replace = T)
effort <-sample(0:4, 1000,replace= T)

bso <- function(effort){
case_when(effort == 0~ 4500,
        effort == 1~ 4300,
        effort == 2~ 3700,
        effort == 3~ 4700, TRUE ~ 5300)
}
bs <- function(effort){
case_when(effort == 0~ 2500,
        effort == 1~ 3300,
        effort == 2~ 3700,
        effort == 3~ 3700, TRUE ~ 3300)
 }
 bs<-bs(effort)
```

Comment: For a how to guide see https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-specification or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet

Comment: ... when applying this it will be much easier if you combine all your data into one data.frame before starting to estimate models.

Comment: how can I merge them ?

Comment: I don't know -- you have not shown any data. Please have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example which describes ways to write questions which will help you get an answer. I also think this is different enough from your question on specifying random effects to warrant a new question.

Comment: I have added my data , do you have any idea for that ?